# For strange reason node module (mysql2) every time throw's Type Error

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, node-modules

I didn't understand how it works. I'm new at JS BUT I didn't get why always when I am calling:

```
function checkUserDb(msg) {
    dbContext.query('SELECT * FROM Users_Table WHERE Id = ?', msg.from.id, function(err, result){
        if (result.length > 0) return true;
        else {
            createUserDb(msg.from.id,msg.from.first_name + ' ' + msg.from.last_name)
            return false;
        }
    });
};

function createUserDb(userId, userName) {
    dbContext.query('INSERT Users_Table(Id,Username,Permision,Level,Upgrade,Experience,Wallet) VALUE (?,?,1,\'Ламер\',\'N/A\',0,0)',[userId,userName]);
}
```

throws an error:

> Process exited with code 1
>
> Uncaught TypeError: this.onResult is not a function

And it always throwing the exception when it finds a cell, i.e when [Text Row] > 0 (I checked in debugger it have a correct data)

Example: I have variable Id (PK) with this I want to find by `SELECT` a cell and do the thing with his data like UPDATE and INSERT query (and proceed it in my program).

Once it worked and created a cell:

[image: Once it worked and created a cell]